# Factory design pattern implementation in rt.jar

Tags: java, factory

I was reading factory design pattern and on one of the links I read the below mentioned fact.

{
Factory pattern which is used along with various Immutable classes likes Boolean e.g. Boolean.valueOf()
}

With this the background, can some one explain how it has been implemented in Boolean and other immutable classes. Apologies if I am missing a silly thing here.

Regards Tarun

Comment: To see _how_ you could see the source code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you see two methods below :

```
public static Boolean valueOf(boolean b) {
    return (b ? TRUE : FALSE);
}

public static Boolean valueOf(String s) {
    return toBoolean(s) ? TRUE : FALSE;
}
```

These are static methods of **Boolean** class and **return Boolean** type object based on parameter that is provided.

So, you don't create **Boolean** object, instead **Boolean** class itself creates/returns(already created) object for you. Hence factory for you.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of returning a `new Boolean()`, it will check the parameter and return one of the existing `Boolean` objects, `Boolean.TRUE` or `Boolean.FALSE`.